# Camera calibration and get relative position of the camera with Opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

Hello all I'm trying to get the relative position of the cameras with one origin
This picture below after calibration the intrinsic parameter he put the checker board at 
the center and get calibrate the extrinsic parameters of multiple cameras

So my understand of the step is

1. To Get the intrinsic parameter with calibration

[image]

> ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints,
> imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
> -> is this rvecs and tvecs for calibration checker board images right?

2. then using this mtx(intrinsic parameter) to get the extrinsic parameter for the origin checker board. <- this part I'm not sure how to do.
   [image]

I want to know my approach is right and how to get the relative position of the cameras with origin checkerboard calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. To get the extrinsic parameters, extract the checkerboard corners from the images, then call cv::solvePnP to the get the camera pose with respect to the checkerboard.

You must ensure that the entire checkerboard is in view, or you'll get an error in translation.